# Need help downloading steam!

Tags: games, downloads, steam

I'm new to ubuntu, I have 14.04 and I've downloaded the steam from the USC that says "the ultimate gaming platform" and it just won't open or respond. I tried downloading the one that says "application for managing and playing games on steam" but it says "There isn’t a software package called “steam” in your current software sources." I;mreallt confused I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you see Steam icon on unity launcher?

Comment: Sorry im such a noob, but what is the unity launcher?

Comment: nvm, Yeah theres 2 icons

Comment: and in my apps theres 3

Comment: What happened when you run Steam? any alart? or crash ?

Comment: Literally nothing, I try to open it and no response

Comment: Open terminal with [CTRL] + [ALT] + [T] and just type "steam"

Comment: /usr/bin/steam: line 191: /home/bailey/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Success
bailey@bailey-p6774y:~$ 
 That's what I got what now?

Comment: Maybe this link helps you:  http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864959809967399994/

Comment: Are you getting these packages from Ubuntu software center?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very helpful article for installing Steam in Ubuntu here -> http://www.dedoimedo.com/games/steam-ubuntu-ringtail.html. Hope this helps.